# What is the point of using (Request $request)?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project and I am having trouble understanding the purpose of (Request $request) which was used as:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request) {
    //code
}
```

I`ve done some research and I think it is about dependency injection but I am having a hard time grasping what dependency injection means in this context.

Comment: This specific example is not about dependency injection, but _type hinting_ - restricting which arguments should be passed into a method

Comment: Basically UserRequest is a class and $request is an object of this class according to my understanding...we can use $request to access any property and methods of this class in our store function.

Comment: would you see this ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.